# svndumpfilter2 to solve svnadmin: Can't write to stream: Broken pipe issue

Tags: svn

I recently moved my "dir1" from "myrepo1/trunk/dir1" to "myrepo1/archives/dir1". Now i want to move that to a new repo all by itself. So I did the following:

```
svnadmin dump myrepo1 | svndumpfilter include --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs archives/dir1  > dumpfile
```

But I get the following error:

```
svndumpfilter: Invalid copy source path '/trunk/dataManagement'
svnadmin: Can't write to stream: Broken pipe
```

I read about this on the internet and want to use svndumpfilter2 (like in http://blog.janjonas.net/2010-02-16/svndumpfilter-svndumpfilter2-extract-svn-paths-to-separated-repository) but i get

```
-bash: ./svndumpfilter2: No such file or directory
svnadmin: Can't write to stream: Broken pipe
```

I want to know how to use this svndumpfilter2 to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. `./svndumpfilter2` is valid if svndumpfilter2 exists in the current directory. svndumpfilter2 is a 3rd party tool that you have to download first. Then replace the dot with the download directory.
2. the message "svnadmin: Can't write to stream: Broken pipe" is a consequence of the previous errors. `svnadmin` keeps feeding its output into the pipe but the other end of the pipe (svndumpfilter in the first example or the non-existing svndumpfilter2 in the second) has terminated without waiting for the end of the stream. just ignore that message.